# How to scrape twitter followers using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape twitter followers. But I only get one at once. How can I scrape all the followers seen on the page ? BTW it's ok to scroll down the page.

```py
browser.get(f"https://www.twitter.com/{username1}/following")
time.sleep(5)
following = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div[1]')

for a in following:

    follower = a.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div[1]').text

    print(follower)
```

Comment: This is the xpath of just one follower, you  need to get the selector of each follower and iterate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 problems in the code.
1:- Absolute path is used. Instead use

```
//div[@dir="ltr"]
```

2:- `find_element_by_xpath` gets only one element. If you want to retrieve multiple elements try using `find_elements_by_xpath`

```
followers = a.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@dir="ltr"]')
for follower in followers:
    print(follower.text())
```